# Error while processing RealmObject descedant after installing Project Lombok

Tags: java, android, realm, lombok

That is my class that I want to store in my Realm database. While building an app it throws `"Error:A default public constructor with no argument must be declared if a custom constructor is declared."` But before using realm it was ok - default constructor was not required. Also I got warnings like that: Warning:(18, 1) `Generating equals/hashCode implementation but without a call to superclass, even though this class does not extend java.lang.Object. If this is intentional, add '@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)' to your type.` How to fix errors?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import io.realm.RealmObject;
import kg.zuber.aqe_android.R;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;

@Data
public class Measure extends RealmObject {
    @Getter
    int id;
    @NonNull
    String name;
    @Getter
    @NonNull
    String slug;

    public Measure(int id, @NonNull String name, @NonNull String slug) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.slug = slug;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public static class MeasureAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Measure> {
        private final Context mContext;
        private ArrayList<Measure> measures;

        public MeasureAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Measure> mMeasures) {
            super(context, R.layout.blue_spinner_item, mMeasures);
            this.mContext = context;
            measures = mMeasures;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Measure device = measures.get(position);
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.blue_spinner_item, parent, false);
            }
            TextView textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            textView.setText(device.name);
            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A default constructor have been a requirement for Realm for a long time. Adding that should fix the error. The warning seems to be related to Lombok somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of only `@Data`, you can use the following:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
```

And remove the hand written constructor.

Also, you don't need the `@Getter` annotations. If you want to have the fields be null-checked, you should use `@lombok.NonNull` or import it instead of `android.support.annotation.NonNull`.

Disclosure: I am a lombok developer.